# Electric Car Charging Android App crashes on start - custom list item and Adapter

Tags: android, listview, github, crash, baseadapter

I am doing a Udacity course on Android Development specifically in Networking atm. I am building an app that find the closest Electric Car Charging points and displays them in a listView. At the moment I am just trying to get the structure working before retrieving live data.

I am using a custom object - ChargePoint- which takes 5 inputs.

I am using a custom adapter - ChargePointAdapter - which translates the 5 bits of info onto the right places in a list_item.xml

My  - MainActivity - stores the placeholder data, creates an adapter with the data, finds the listView from activity_main.xml and sets the adapter.

I dont get any errors, however my app crashes on start.

Here is a link to the project: https://github.com/Kovah101/ChargeMyCar

EDIT: On further inspection the app runs when I comment out the line:

```
chargePointListView.setAdapter(adapter)
```

which I assume means my custom adapter class isnt to blame? The only difference in the Log outputs from the running to non running version is

```
09-21 18:08:54.533 20790-20790/com.example.android.chargemycar I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20790 SIG: 9
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: if theres a crash...theres a log.

Comment: list like your adapter is written wrong. where is the viewholder?

Comment: I'll run it again and look at the log, i'll also look at the adapter again, thanks!

Comment: I get 10 warnings about `split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status` 0-9 and `dependancies`. I also get 4 info messages - 1.InstantRun , 2.HwCust: constructor found, 3.HwSecImmHelper: mSecuirityInputMethodService is null , 4.Process: send signal. Nothing looks that bad but i have untrained eyes

Comment: if you app works when u comment out that adapter line, then your error is within the adapter for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there were a few little errors, DroiDev was correct in saying the adapter had caused the error, since commenting out that line allowed the app to run.

I went through each part of my ChargePointAdapter and found `TextView distanceTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(distance);` which should have been `R.id.distance`, fixing that didnt solve my problem so I commented out the whole `distance` chunk to start a process of elmination through the app. First time and that solved the crash so the error was in

`TextView distanceTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.distance);
        String distance = Double.toString(currentChargePoint.getDistance());
        distanceTextView.setText(distance);`

theoretically that all worked so I looked at my xml and my parent View had the `id/distance` not my `textView`, correcting that fixed everything, the Github is updated with the working code now too.

Keep looking down the Rabit Hole (Thanks DroiDev)